# What are the 8 directions in Sanskrit and the corresponding Adhi Devata (Presiding Deity)?

Tags: gods

I have heard that Hinduism recognizes 8 directions (plus up and down). What are these in Sanskrit and in English and who is the corresponding presiding deity for each?

Comment: The main reason for asking this question is to understand if there are any regional variations.